# Is there a more efficient way to append multiple columns from the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, database-performance

I'd like to return multiple values from the same record, with different columns of the same type appended under one another.  I could do multiple joins, but that seems very inefficient because of the multiple table scans.

```
declare @gameID as VarChar(30)
select @gameID = '20210829-SLNvsPIT-0'

select Vis1ID as VisID, Vis1 as Vis, Home1 as Home, Home1ID as HomeID
from Baseball.dbo.GameLogs
where GameID = @gameID
union
select Vis2ID, Vis2, Home2, Home2ID
from Baseball.dbo.GameLogs
where GameID = @gameID
union
.......
select Vis9ID, Vis9, Home9, Home9ID
from Baseball.dbo.GameLogs
where GameID = @gameID
```

Returns:

| VisID | Vis | Home | HomeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arenn001 | Nolan Arenado | Colin Moran | morac001 |
| badeh001 | Harrison Bader | Anthony Alford | alfoa002 |
| carld002 | Dylan Carlson | Yoshi Tsutsugo | tsuty001 |
| edmat001 | Tommy Edman | Kevin Newman | newmk001 |
| goldp001 | Paul Goldschmidt | Ke'Bryan Hayes | hayek001 |
| kim-k001 | Kwang Kim | Wil Crowe | croww001 |
| moliy001 | Yadier Molina | Jacob Stallings | stalj001 |
| oneit001 | Tyler O'Neill | Bryan Reynolds | reynb001 |
| sosae001 | Edmundo Sosa | Cole Tucker | tuckc001 |

This is exactly what I'm looking for, but it's painfully slow.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Its probably slow because you are using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. Union is certainly the correct way to accomplish what you are doing. Of course a better table design would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpivot each row. This means that you only scan the table once, then break it out into separate rows. You could use `UNPIVOT`, but `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` is far more flexible.

```sql
DECLARE @gameID varchar(30) = '20210829-SLNvsPIT-0';

SELECT
  v.VisID,
  v.Vis,
  v.Home,
  v.HomeID
FROM dbo.GameLogs gl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (Vis1ID, Vis1, Home1, Home1ID),
    (Vis2ID, Vis2, Home2, Home2ID),
    (Vis3ID, Vis3, Home3, Home3ID),
    (Vis4ID, Vis4, Home4, Home4ID) -- .....
) v(VisID, Vis, Home, HomeID)
WHERE gl.GameID = @gameID;
```

It goes without saying that your table is seriously denormalized and should be redesigned pronto.